# Relation between initial current and current amplitude in $RLC$ circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, resonance, inductance

Let $\phi$ be the so called phase-angle, which measures how much the voltage $V(t)$ leads the current $i(t)$ in a $RLC$ circuit. How would you justify the relation $$i(t=0)=i_m\cos\phi$$

where $i_m$ is the maximum current, or current amplitude. I believe this equation is valid, but it might not be in its most general form. Should I set up a differential equation in terms of the charge $Q(t)$ of the circuit components? Differentiating that would then give information about $i(t)$.

Comment: You can solve this using the Laplace transform approach and have a closed form solution that is valid for the transient as well as steady-state.  [Here is](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525974/equation-20-16-proof/527788#527788) an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
i(0)&=V(0)/Z\\
&=\frac{V_m}{Z}cos(\omega ~ 0 +\phi)\\
&=i_m\cos \phi
\end{align}
$$

where $Z$ is the impedance of the circuit and $V_m$ the maximum voltage. Since the phase angle $\phi$ is already given, the current can always be written in terms of that.

> Should I set up a differential equation in terms of the charge Q(t) of the circuit components

You may and you probably will if you are going to analyse this circuit. Setting up a differential equation, or analysing the circuit using phasors or any other technique will be illuminating.

- in particular you will realise that $Z$ is exactly same as $R$ in its effect but is strangely contributed to in addition, by both $L$ and $C$. In fact one may even *imagine* it for $L$ & $C$.
- You will also realise where the cosine comes from.
- Most important of all, if you solve the equations, you will see revealed before your eyes the awesome phenomenon of resonance.

What you'll get is a non-homogeneous, second order ordinary linear differential equation. Its not so bad. Its driven damped SHM. Remember for ODEs, $a$ solution is $the$ solution.